# Fail2Ban blocking behaviours depending on the status code

Tags: nginx, security, fail2ban

I am using Fail2Ban and I have configured it as needed. This is reading logs from nginx/error.log and is acting depending on configs about maxretry and timing sets. The question is that is this possible to have different rules depending on status codes?

For instance, I want to block anyone getting 10 `404 Status code` in 5 minutes, but to block anyone getting 3 `403 Status code`.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's some examples from a popular Gist several years ago: https://gist.github.com/JulienBlancher/48852f9d0b0ef7fd64c3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should add a filter in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/` with a relevant name - e.g. `nginx-{403,404}.conf`.

They should contain something like the following lines :

nginx-403.conf :

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 403
ignoreregex =
```

nginx-404.conf :

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 404
ignoreregex =
```

Then you should call them from your `jail.local` file, create this file if it is not yet present (which extends the default `jail.conf` file):

For 403 :

```
[nginx-403]

enabled = true
port    = http,https
logpath = /var/log/nginx/access.log
maxretry = 5
findtime = 300
```

And for 404 :

```
[nginx-404]

enabled = true
port    = http,https
logpath = /var/log/nginx/access.log
maxretry = 10
findtime = 300
```

Note: if you are running an old version of Fail2Ban (version 0.8.x and lower), you also need to define `filter` in your config. In newer versions the jail heading in square brackets also identifies the filter being used.

Comment: the `filter` lines are no longer needed in the jail files - see optimising fail2ban filters http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/fail2ban-filters/

Comment: how does it ban?

Comment: @chovy to quote from that webpage linked by the previous commenter, "In Fail2Ban 0.9.x the jail heading in square brackets also identifies the filter being used."

Comment: @chovy Maybe you mean if you add the config above to your jail.local which extends your jail.conf file (let me also update the answer).
Meaning in jail.config there should be a default action defined (which is _action, meaning ban only).  Moreover, findtime and maxretry is used to decide when to ban. A host is banned if it has generated "maxretry" during the last "findtime" in seconds. Hope this helps.