# Fail2Ban: RegEx to filter all 404 errors out of the Apache-log

Tags: apache2, regex, fail2ban

In my logs I regularly see loads of 404-errors where bots obviously do scan the server systematically for specific software installations. As this also causes loads of traffic, I want to ban them.

So based on some HowTos I tried to find a RegEx for fail2ban which filters these 404-requests out of the Apache-logs and based on this blocks the related IPs.

Unfortunately none of the RegEx patterns I found and tried do work. So as an example:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/other*access.log '^<HOST> - .* "(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 404 .*$'
```

(which looks good to me) does not find anything:

```
Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1210] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)ExYear[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 1210 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 1210 missed
```

There defintely are several 404-Errors in that logfile. So what Am I doing wrong? How should a proper RegEx look lie to get all the 404s?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the default apache-badbots has what you are looking for https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/filter.d/apache-badbots.conf

Comment: @Turdie no, this filter blocks bots by their name, I want to block based on too many 404-errors

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1472595/fail2ban-404-bruteforcing-sharex

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/911008/mitigating-404-bomb-with-nginx

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/849854/fail2ban-blocking-behaviours-depending-on-the-status-code

Answer (score 1):

`other_vhosts_access.log` by default has a different `LogFormat vhost_combined` which is prefixed by a `vhost:port` when compared with the standard `common` `LogFormat`. You need to modify the regex accordingly.

Comment: OK, now a
fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/other*access.log '^<HOST>.* - - .* "(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 404 .*$'
ends up with several hundred of matches. But when I add
failregex =  ^<HOST>.* - - .* "(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 404 .*$
ignoreregex =.*(robots.txt|favicon.ico|jpg|png|sitemap|sitemap.txt|sitemap.xml.gz|sitemap_index.xml)
to my filter, fail2.ban still does not find anything...

Comment: Please post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one

```
failregex = ^<HOST> - .* "(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 404 .*$
ignoreregex =.*(robots.txt|favicon.ico|jpg|png)
```

Comment: Related: https://forum.cleavr.io/t/how-to-block-404-attacks-using-fail2ban/303